# Android ListView count numbers

Tags: android

I've a question, how can i get the total count of items that are in a `ListView`. You can put many numbers in it (example: 1,20€ , 2,20€...).
And how I can get the total count and set it in to a `TextView`.
The numbers where added from a edittext.toString(without the €).

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String list_view_count_text = new_order_count.getText().toString();
            String list_view_price_text = new_order_price.getText().toString();
            if(TextUtils.isEmpty(list_view_count_text)){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Bitte gebe eine Anzahl ein!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            if(TextUtils.isEmpty(list_view_price_text)){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Bitte gebe einen Preis ein!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            list_view_order_list.add(0, spinner_new_order_subitem.getSelectedItem().toString());
            list_view_order_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            list_view_count_list.add(0, list_view_count_text);
            list_view_price_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            list_view_price_list.add(0, list_view_price_text);
            list_view_count_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            newOrderDialog.hide();

        }
    });
```

and after this it should new calculate.

Merry Christmas and thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the total sum of **list_view_price_list** try this

```
int sum;
for( int i = 0; i < list_view_price_list.size(); i++ )
{
    String price = mListViewLocation.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
    price.substring(1); //to remove  €
    sum += Integer.parseInt( price );
}
```

Comment: It works, but only with integers but i need for floats (2.20...), do you know how?

Comment: ohh, float.parsefloat... hahah Thank you!